# Hacer referencia a elementos de un array en vez del elemento html

Tags: javascript, html, array, binding

Estoy haciendo el juego de Tic tac toe. Tengo un `array listaDeCasillas` que contiene los `divs` con la clase `.tablero__casilla` a los que les tengo que agregar un `eventListener 'click'` para que hagan una determinada función.

```js
const listaDeCasillas = document.getElementsByClassName('tablero__casilla');
        
for (let casilla of listaDeCasillas) {
  casilla.addEventListener("click", hacerAlgo);
}
        
function hacerAlgo() {
  console.log(this);
}
```

```html
<div class="tablero">
      <div class="tablero__casilla">O</div>
      <div class="tablero__casilla">O</div>
      <div class="tablero__casilla">O</div>
      <div class="tablero__casilla">O</div>
      <div class="tablero__casilla">O</div>
      <div class="tablero__casilla">O</div>
      <div class="tablero__casilla">O</div>
      <div class="tablero__casilla">O</div>
      <div class="tablero__casilla">O</div>
    </div>
```

Mi problema es que al hacer click en ellos, estoy haciendo referencia al elemento en el DOM y no al elemento del array. Quiero saber si es posible hacer referencia al elemento del array. Sé que se puede hacer algo con `.bind()` pero no sé cómo.

De modo que, en vez de que me aparezca: `<div class="tablero__casilla">O</div>`

Me salga algo como: `listaDeCasillas[i]`

Answer (score 0):

te comento que en primer lugar no tienes un array convencional de **listaDeCasillas**, tienes es un array **HTMLCollection** de la misma, lo cual es distinto, su uso lo desconozco, pero de igual manera puedes leer más al respecto aquí:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

Sin embargo, dando una solución a tu problema, te recomiendo usar **data-id** para asignar un id a cada elemento de tu tic tac toe, así, puedes llamarlo mediante el evento usado.

```js
const listaDeCasillas = document.getElementsByClassName("tablero__casilla");

for (let casilla of listaDeCasillas) {
  casilla.addEventListener("click", hacerAlgo);
}

function hacerAlgo() {
  console.log(this.getAttribute("data-id"));
}

console.log(listaDeCasillas);
```

```html
<div class="tablero">
  <div data-id="1" class="tablero__casilla">O</div>
  <div data-id="2" class="tablero__casilla">O</div>
  <div data-id="3" class="tablero__casilla">O</div>
  <div data-id="4" class="tablero__casilla">O</div>
  <div data-id="5" class="tablero__casilla">O</div>
  <div data-id="6" class="tablero__casilla">O</div>
  <div data-id="7" class="tablero__casilla">O</div>
  <div data-id="8" class="tablero__casilla">O</div>
  <div data-id="9" class="tablero__casilla">O</div>
</div>
```